# the post thumbnail, scale

Tags: post-thumbnails

I'm trying to figure how to scale the_post_thumbnail to a specific width? 
Can you guys help?

Currently I'm using

```
<?php
        //Resize post thumbnail
        $thumbnail = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( get_the_ID() ), 'single-post-thumbnail' );
        $thumbnailHeight = $thumbnail[1];
        $thumbnailWidth = $thumbnail[2];
        if($thumbnailHeight != 0){
            $ratio = $thumbnailWidth/$thumbnailHeight;
            $width = 220;
            $height = $width * $ratio;
        }else{
            $height = $thumbnailHeight;
            $width = $thumbnailWidth;
        }
    ?>
```

And printing the thumbnail with

```
 <img src="<?php echo $thumbnail[0]; ?>" width="<?php echo $width; ?>" height="<?php echo $height; ?>"/>
```

It works but....

Thanks!

Comment: What you are asking here ?

Comment: How to use this function http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_post_thumbnail to display a scaled thumbnail! Regards

Comment: I want to scale the image, based on a specific width 220px. I don't know the height!

Comment: @amit please don't post **answers** as **comments**.

Comment: Joao, if my answer below worked out for you, could you please accept it as correct for future users.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

You could use:

```
add_image_size( 'category-thumb', 220, 9999 ); //220 pixels wide (and unlimited height)
```

and then to display:

```
if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { the_post_thumbnail( 'category-thumb' ); }
```

This will create a thumbnail size of 220 by "unlimited"...  Set the featured image on the post, then use the display code in your theme to show the 220x??? scaled image.

Comment: Bingo! Note also that, as far as I know, passing an array to `the_post_thumbnail()` still doesn't work. Adding an image size, and then calling it via `the_post_thumbnail()` is the best and, really, only way to go.

Answer (score 1):

Pretty new to Wordpress and PHP, so have been cutting and crow-baring code together at the moment.  This might be of some help so i thought I would post, basically I have a slider on my front page with a custom thumbnail size, and also a custom thumbnail size on my blog roll page.  I also needed to link the images on my blog roll page to the post.

First I created I added theme support for the thumbnails in functions.php

```
<?php   /* CUSTOM POST THUMBNAILS */
if ( function_exists( 'add_theme_support' ) ) {
add_theme_support('post-thumbnails');
add_image_size('nivothumb', 960, 320, true);
add_image_size('postthumb', 690, 230, true);
}
?>
```

Then for the nivoslider I used the below code, on my front_page.php along with some loop code.

```
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail('nivothumb'); ?></a>
```

Then for the blog roll thumbnail image I used the following, on my index.php along with the some loop code.

```
<?php if ( has_post_thumbnail()) : ?>
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>">
<?php the_post_thumbnail('postthumb');?></a>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Not sure if this is of some help and if this is not the best way to do it I would be interested to know.

Cheers,

Ant

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to mention `timthumb` aswell. 
you can do anything you want with this.

all info 
http://code.google.com/p/timthumb/ 
or 
http://www.binarymoon.co.uk/projects/timthumb/